# connection error while trying to migrate table in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i'm using visual studio 2022 and ASP.NET core 6 MVC. i'm trying to migrate a table named "Category" to Sql Server database using Entity Framework and i'm getting this error

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was provided by an authority that is not approved..)

Comment: Please note that *all* content on [so] needs to be in English; that *includes* error messages.

Comment: At a guess, based on the English part of the error, you are trying to use an encrypted connection but the SQL Server you are connecting to probably has the default self-signed certificate?

Comment: It seems to be "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"

Comment: SQL Server instances are installed with a self-signed certificate by default so they aren't trusted by any tools expecting CA-signed certificates. Since you apparently have `Encrypt=true` in your connection string properties have you tried adding `TrustServerCertificate=true` as well? Ref: [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient # SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring)

Comment: i didn't have Encrypt=true but it worked with TrustServerCertificate=true, thank you so much.